# file association points to incorrect version

Tags: windows

I have a software with multiple versions installed. I am trying to change the file association to a specific version by right clicking (Open With) and selecting the correct exe file but the document keeps opening in the previous version. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I have an idea that whatever you said above is not accurate - so it is not working. What you've explained is the correct process, so I have to assume what you explained is not what was actually done. Please provide more information and exact steps, maybe some screenshots to help. Did you also select "Always open" with this program?

Comment: Yes I selected `Always use this app to open` option. I tested the following process in two computers and the same problem arises.

1. Originally associate the file to software `/bin/myprogram/version2`
2. Then click `Open WIth` and associate to `/bin/myprogram/version1` but it will open with version 2

I think this problem have to do with the Windows registry. The program name is the same so Windows do not see a reason to change the association.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using Windows 11 Pro, and it is simply not smart enough to do this through the normal interface.  Fortunately, there is a workaround.

Your system contains a list of applications and their specific paths.  Apparently there is only one path per application name, but you can change it.

Below is the path to the key I had to change. Yours will have different details.

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-380783119-1585622524-2864582427-1001\Software\Classes\Applications\UltiMaker-Cura.exe\shell\open\command
```

My suggestion:

- Find the name of the executable you want.
- Open regedit
- If you have any doubt about your regedit skills, start with File -> Export and save the current state of your registry.
- Search for the executable name
- When you find it under \Software\Classes\Applications, click down from there to shell\open\command
- Now you will see the actual path name.  Change it to the one you want.

In my case I changed

```
C:\Program Files\UltiMaker Cura 5.4.0\UltiMaker-Cura.exe
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\UltiMaker Cura 5.6.0\UltiMaker-Cura.exe
```

For reference these did not work:

1. Through system settings change the association to the one I wanted using "Choose an app on your PC", choosing the preferred version.
2. Through system settings change the file to some program with a different name, and then back to the one I wanted, selecting the version as in item 1.